# Proof of Poincare's Inclusion-Exclusion Indicator Function Formula by Induction

Tags: measure-theory, induction, lebesgue-measure, inclusion-exclusion

The Poincare's inclusion exclusion formula is given by

\begin{align} \Bbb{I}_{\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n}A_j}=\sum_{1\leq j\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_j}+\sum^{n}_{r=2}(-1)^{r+1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \cdots\cap A_{i_r} }\end{align}
where $\Bbb{I}$ represents the indicator function. I want to prove this formula by induction. Below is my work

**MY TRIAL**

Assume true for $n,$ that is for $P_{n}$

\begin{align} \Bbb{I}_{\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n}A_j}=\sum_{1\leq j\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_j}+\sum^{n}_{r=2}(-1)^{r+1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \cdots\cap A_{i_r} }\end{align}
Now \begin{align} \bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n+1}A_j=\left(\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n}A_j\right)\cup A_{n+1}\end{align}
Applying the indicator function rule,

\begin{align} \Bbb{I}_{\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n+1}A_j}=\Bbb{I}_{\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n}A_{n}}+\Bbb{I}_{A_{n+1}}-\Bbb{I}_{\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n}A_{n}}\Bbb{I}_{A_{n+1}}\end{align}
So, we apply $P_n$ to get

\begin{align} \Bbb{I}_{\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n+1}A_j}=&\sum_{1\leq j\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_j}+\sum^{n}_{r=2}(-1)^{r+1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \cdots\cap A_{i_r} }\\&+\Bbb{I}_{A_{n+1}}-\Bbb{I}_{\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n}A_{n}}\Bbb{I}_{A_{n+1}}
\\=&\sum_{1\leq j\leq n+1}\Bbb{I}_{A_j}+\sum^{n}_{r=2}(-1)^{r+1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \cdots\cap A_{i_r} }\\&-\Bbb{I}_{\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n}A_{n}}\Bbb{I}_{A_{n+1}}
\end{align}
Again, applying $P_{n}$, to the last term, we get

\begin{align} \Bbb{I}_{\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n+1}A_j}=&\sum_{1\leq j\leq n+1}\Bbb{I}_{A_j}+\sum^{n}_{r=2}(-1)^{r+1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \cdots\cap A_{i_r} }\\&-\left(\sum_{1\leq j\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_j}+\sum^{n}_{r=2}(-1)^{r+1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \cdots\cap A_{i_r} }\right)\Bbb{I}_{A_{n+1}}
\\=&\sum_{1\leq j\leq n+1}\Bbb{I}_{A_j}+\sum^{n}_{r=2}(-1)^{r+1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \cdots\cap A_{i_r} }\\&-\sum_{1\leq j\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_j}\Bbb{I}_{A_{n+1}}+\sum^{n}_{r=2}(-1)^{r+1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \cdots\cap A_{i_r} }\Bbb{I}_{A_{n+1}}
\end{align}
From here, I'm not sure how to continue. Any help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your last line observe that
$$\Bbb{I}_{A_j}\Bbb{I}_{A_{n+1}}
=\Bbb{I}_{A_{j}\cap A_{n+1}}$$
and
$$\Bbb{I}_{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \cdots\cap A_{i_r} }\Bbb{I}_{A_{n+1}}
=\Bbb{I}_{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \cdots\cap A_{i_r}\cap A_{n+1}}.$$
These terms provide the indicator functions of the multiple intersections
of the $A_i$ that involve $A_{n+1}$.

Comment: I am afraid to tell you that I already know that but the challenge is how to finally arrive at \begin{align} \Bbb{I}_{\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n+1}A_j}=&\sum_{1\leq j\leq n+1}\Bbb{I}_{A_j}+\sum^{n}_{r=2}(-1)^{r+1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\leq n}\Bbb{I}_{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \cdots\cap A_{i_r} }\Bbb{I}_{A_{n+1}}
\end{align}